# NullPointerException trying to access a String resource

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception, android-assets

I have the following /res/values/uris.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="bladder">blahblah</string>
</resources>
```

I am accessing it in code:

```
private String bladderUrl= getString(R.string.bladder);
```

But it is returning null. I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My guess you placed bladderUrl smth like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    private String bladderUrl = getString(R.string.bladder);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...
```

However you need to do smth like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    private String bladderUrl;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        bladderUrl = getString(R.string.bladder);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all to clear that up. You **don't** have to have all your strings in `strings.xml`. Period.

Emmanuels answer is partially right. You have to get the string inside your `onCreate()` method when the context is initialized. His answer is only partially correct since he also mentioned that you have to have the strings inside the strings.xml which is not true.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure these values are in the file strings.xml.

Also, you can't access the strings from the constructor. The application context is not yet initialized. You should do it in onCreate().

Emmanuel

Comment: @Sheehan Alam then most likely you have problems with app design.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. This string is in an activity but the onCreate() is in the subclass or something? Just move your string to the subclass or make it protected. You just can't access the application context from your constructor so you'll have to do it later.