# Android: Referring to a string resource when defining a log name

Tags: java, android

In my Android app, I want to use a single variable for the log name in multiple files. At the moment, I'm specifying it separately in each file, e.g.

```
public final String LOG_NAME = "LogName";
Log.d(LOG_NAME, "Logged output);
```

I've tried this:

```
public final String LOG_NAME = (String) getText(R.string.app_name_nospaces);
```

And while this works in generally most of my files, Eclipse complains about one of them:

> The method getText(int) is undefined
>   for the type DatabaseManager

I've made sure I'm definitely importing android.content.Context in that file. If I tell it exactly where to find getText:

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getText(int)
>   from the type      Context
>     - The method getText(int) is undefined for the type DatabaseManager

I'm sure I've committed a glaringly obvious n00b error, but I just can't see it! Thanks for all help: if any other code snippets would help, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because getText is a method of `Context`. It does not matter if you import the Context class; what matters is that you invoke that method **from a Context** (for instance, the Activity class is a Context (it inherits Context)).

In that case, what I'd recommend, is creating a Application class that returns the context you want. [Here I explain how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391720/android-how-can-i-get-a-resources-object-from-a-static-context/4391811#4391811). After that you can do something like:

```
public final String LOG_NAME = (String) App.getContext().getText(R.string.app_name_nospaces);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work great, and I feel like I better understand what's going on now. The only place it doesn't work is in the application class itself: I thought I'd be able to just use getText there (as it's a context), but I get a NullPointerException. Any suggestions?

Comment: Got it working, thanks to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157228/nullpointerexception-trying-to-access-a-string-resource Turns out the resources aren't accessible until onCreate, so I've made my LOG_NAME static, rather than final, and set it inside onCreate rather than on declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what sort of 'files' you are using, you can define a TAG that is used.

For example, when I create an app, I like to create a base class for my Activity classes...

Suppose my app is called 'Wibble', and my package is `com.mydomain.Wibble`...I create my base Activity like so...

```
package com.mydomain.Wibble

public class WibbleActivity extends Activity {

    final protected String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // I'll explain how this next line works later
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Entered onCreate()...");
    }
}
```

Now suppose I derive an activity as follows...

```
package com.mydomain.Wibble

public class SomeActivity extends WibbleActivity {

    @Override
    protexted void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Don't Log "Entered onCreate()..." - WibbleActivity does it for me
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "SomeText");
    }
}
```

Then I derive another Activity...

```
package com.mydomain.Wibble

public class SomeOtherActivity extends WibbleActivity {

    @Override
    protexted void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Don't Log "Entered onCreate()..." - WibbleActivity does it for me
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "SomeOtherText");
    }
```

When `onCreate()` is called for `SomeActivity`, the output will be...

```
com.mydomain.Wibble.SomeActivity    Entered onCreate()...
com.mydomain.Wibble.SomeActivity    SomeText
```

...when `onCreate()` is called for `SomeOtherActivity` however, the output will be...

```
com.mydomain.Wibble.SomeOtherActivity    Entered onCreate()...
com.mydomain.Wibble.SomeOtherActivity    SomeOtherText
```

Neither activity needs to know specifics through an explicit string and the package name is prefixed. Obviously it will only work in certain situations but I find it useful.